# What is the use of pom.xml in Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have just started working with Maven in Eclipse.

I tried running a sample program in it, and I encountered some problems. The errors were in my pom.xml file. What is the significance of the pom.xml file in Maven?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In short the `pom.xml` will have all information to build your project.

For example you want to build a project and you have only the `pom.xml` sent to you via mail. If there are enough entries in the `pom.xml` then that is all you need! You can import it to Eclipse, Maven will download your source code from CVS, download various dependency jars (like Spring, Apache Commons), run your test cases, build the jar/war, deploy to your jboss/app server, generate a report of your code quality (using Sonar, maybe). Each task you want to do will be mentioned as a `goal`.

The links already provided are good enough for reference.

Comment: Can you suggest a link where such a thing is captured. I have the same requirement and I am fairly new to Maven.

Answer (score 19):

POM is an XML file that contains the project configuration details used by Maven. It provides all the configurations required for a project.

**POM** means **Project Object Model**, and, as the name suggests, it defines the model of the project as well.

In the normal project development you will add JAR files and libraries as required. In **Maven**-based development, those JAR files, libraries are added to the project using this **pom.xml**. In the **pom** context we call those JAR files, libraries as **dependencies**.

Answer (score 10):

Maven is a build tool and `pom.xml` is the main file for the project.

#### The POM

The `pom.xml` file is the core of a project's configuration in Maven. It is a single configuration file that contains the majority of the information required to build a project in just the way you want. The POM is huge and can be daunting in its complexity, but it is not necessary to understand all of the intricacies just yet to use it effectively.

For more reference, check *[Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)*.

Comment: What do the dependencies stand for in the pom.xml file ?

Comment: Dependencies are the libraries you would use in your application. If you are not using Maven, You have to download these jar files manually from the internet and add it to your project libraries. But with maven, You can just updated pom.xml with the dependency you want and, Maven will do the downloading and adding it to your project.

Answer (score 6):

POM stands for *project object model*. It's the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used to build the project. It downloads required libraries easily using POM XML tags.

Answer (score 6):

When there is no Maven, it needs to add all the library JAR files one by one to the project. But when there is Pom.xml there is no need to add library JAR files one by one.

Simply add the dependency to the Pom.xml, and it will automatically add the library JAR files to the project.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Is POM.xml similar to YAML file in Kubernetes?

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth pom.xml is more like what nuget is to dotnet csproj files.

Answer (score 4):

pom.xml is a file which describes the project, configures plugins, and declares dependencies. The POM names the project, provides a set of unique identifiers (called coordinates) for a project, and defines the relationships between this project and others through dependencies, parents, and prerequisites.

A POM file can include a modules section, which tells Maven which directories have POM files which need to be built.

In the build section you can define plugins for which you need to build the artifacts in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Pom.xml is part of your maven project, using pom.xml, maven life cycle you can achieve it.
The pom.xml is a project object model which tells everything 3rd party tool dependencies and library's and required plugins it will give everything to your project like project means any java based web content like itself. once you create the maven project you will get the pom.xml blog which is everything to  handle your project

If you want to test your project, you need to add testing dependencies which is the maven community it will provide you once added it will have everything tested.